# Getting Math.pow to return a correct value?

Tags: java, double, long-integer, primitive-types

how can I make this expression not end up being a zero.

```
        double dBaseFitness = (double) baseFitness;
        x.shortfitness = (long)(Math.pow(dbaseFitness, dbaseFitness/8.0)/100.0)
                *(long)(Math.pow((double)x.genome.GSIZE, -.1)/100.0);
```

x.shortfitness is a long value. x.Genome.GSIZE is an int.

The only reason I am dividing each expression by 100 is so that the result doesn't exceed the max value of the long type.

Comment: What are the datatypes of baseFitness and x.shortfitness?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill @SteveKuo, thank you both, I updated the expresion to use only double values but I still get a 0. Where do I make the cast to a long?

Comment: Perhaps the real answer is less than 1, so it's being truncated to 0? It would help to assign the answer to a double and print it out before assigning it to your long, so we could see what the value is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `baseFitness` an integer? If so then `baseFitness/8` does integer division. For example `7/8` will yield `0`. Change your `8` and `100` to `8d` and `100d` to force floating point division.

Answer (score 1):

If both the operands of an arithmetic expression are integral types, then the result will be too. So, for example, if "baseFitness" is an integer less than 8, then baseFitness/8 will be zero. Use "8.0" and "100.0" instead.